# Visual Studio Express, Win32 Console App

Tags: c++

So, I`m trying to use Visual Studio Express and I click new project, empty project and unselect SDL Checks. But when I try to debug my code I get an error saying 'Unable to start program Missing .exe file in Debug folder'. How can I fix this?

Comment: http://imgur.com/jieae3E

Comment: Try to build the thing, Ctrl + Shift + B.

Comment: You did add code? You need at least the main function to successfully compile

Comment: I did, I'm just starting out with Visual Studio. Here's my code:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
 cout << "Richard Roy\n";
}

Comment: I pressed Ctrl + Shift + B, and It worked. Thanks, I tried to build it by right clicking it in the solutions explorer but didn`t seem to work. But It's working now Thanks!